# Symfony- passing post params returns the same

Tags: php, symfony, response, symfony-3.4, post-parameter

I defined my postParams where I want to pass "hash" value from db.

What I am trying to accomplish is that if hash exists in my Session table to return TRUE and if not to return FLASE.

Problem is my code always returns TRUE.

What I am missing?

```
$postData = $this->requirePostParams(['hash']);

$this->container->get('app')->formService(
        $this->data['hash']
    );

if ($postData['hash']) {

    $hash = $this->get('app')->getSessionRepository()->find($this->data['hash']);

    if (!$hash) return false;

} else {

    return true;

}
```

And my requirePostParams works fine! (tested on other functions)

```
protected function requirePostParams($params) {

    $currentRequest = $this->get('request_stack')->getCurrentRequest();

    $postData = $currentRequest->request->all();

    $postContent = json_decode($currentRequest->getContent(), true);

    if(!empty($postContent)) $postData = $postContent;

    $this->data = $postData;

    $missingParams = [];

    foreach ($params as $param) {

        if (!array_key_exists($param, $postData)) {

            $missingParams[] = $param;

        }

    }

}
```

And my service:

```
$findHash = $this->getSessionRepository()->findOneBy([
        'hash' => $hash
    ]);
```

Comment: hmm... shouldn't you return smth from `requirePostParams()`?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I updated my code :) @xmike

Answer (score 0):

As xmike mentioned in comments, function `requirePostParams` returns nothing. That's why `$postData['hash']` is never set.

Try to replace `$postData['hash']` with `$this->data['hash']`:

```
$this->requirePostParams(['hash']);

$this->container->get('app')->formService(
        $this->data['hash']
    );

if ($this->data['hash']) {

    $hash = $this->get('app')->getSessionRepository()->find($this->data['hash']);

    if (!$hash) return false;

} else {

    return true;

}
```